# Symbol for function composition

Tags: functions, notation, math-history

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [History of $f \circ g$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132967/history-of-f-circ-g)

Choice of symbols can be an indicator of intellectual allegiance. Consider how, back in the day (and before LaTeX regularised things so much!), the choice of $\neg, \to$ as against $\sim, \supset$ was an indicator of how you felt about natural deduction.

A simple query some older hands here might know the answer to. When and where did the symbol for function composition as in $$f \circ g$$
originate, and when did it become common? It was used in Bourbaki, *Theory of Sets* (p. 78). Was this another of Bourbaki's symbolic innovations? Was early adoption of the symbol by others an indicator of Bourbachiste enthusiasm?

Comment: Isn't this the same question as [History of $f\circ g$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/132967/856)?

Comment: How did one's choice of symbols for logical operands reflect one's attitude towards natural deduction? And when was that?

Comment: @Rahul Drat, I missed that! Though any further info most welcome.

Comment: @K.Stm. Consider the usage in early axiomatic presentations (Hilbert Ackermann) vs. Gentzen.

Comment: @PeterSmith Can you elaborate on that or refer to a page or paper where people explained their conscious choice to use one variant rather than the other?